# Alternatives to #pragma that work inside methods in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, pragma

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313492/pragma-mark-not-showing-in-methods-in-xcode-4-0) [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616748/how-to-view-comments-in-the-method-navigator-of-xcode-4), #pragmas inside methods don't work in Xcode 4.

What's a good way to do quick navigation to different sections within a long method, for example to specific cases of a switch statement?

(I try to keep methods clean & short where practical, but that's a topic for [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676091/is-there-any-research-on-ideal-method-length).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for...
What I like to do is to simply use code blocks like so:

```
// some code

{
     // some code that should stay together
} // [a comment that explains what the code does]
```

This at least allows you to use Xcode's code folding: When you fold in the block between the two `{ }`, you get `{...} // [your explanatory comment]`

It is also great to limit the scope of variables and can (very) slightly improve memory efficiency.

Comment: Best answer so far, but please keep 'em coming!